# How to sort list by length of the first string element?

Tags: python, list

I've imported a list from a .txt file that looks like this

```
[['George Washington'],
 ['John Adams'],
 ['Thomas Jefferson'],
 ['James Madison'],
 ['James Monroe'],
 ['John Quincy Adams'],
 ['Andrew Jackson'],
 ['Martin Van Buren'],
 ['William Henry Harrison'],
 ['John TyIer'],
...
```

I want to sort the list by the length of the first name in ascending order and display only the top 6, but nothing I tried seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to sort by a key? Can you extract the first word from each element? Do you know how to find the length of a string? Can you combine these three items into one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [['George Washington'],
 ['John Adams'],
 ['Thomas Jefferson'],
 ['James Madison'],
 ['James Monroe'],
 ['John Quincy Adams'],
 ['Andrew Jackson'],
 ['Martin Van Buren'],
 ['William Henry Harrison'],
 ['John TyIer']]

l.sort(key = lambda x: len(x[0].split()[0]))
print(l[:6])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a list of lists, which is a little weird. So you need to test not for just the fist name, which you can get by `split()`ing the name, but the first name of the first item in the list.

With that, you might do something like:

```
pres = [['George Washington'],
 ['John Adams'],
 ['Thomas Jefferson'],
 ['James Madison'],
 ['James Monroe'],
 ['John Quincy Adams'],
 ['Andrew Jackson'],
 ['Martin Van Buren'],
 ['William Henry Harrison'],
 ['John TyIer']
]

sorted(pres, key=lambda x: len(x[0].split()[0]), reverse=True)[0:6]
```

Which results in:

```
[['William Henry Harrison'],
 ['George Washington'],
 ['Thomas Jefferson'],
 ['Andrew Jackson'],
 ['Martin Van Buren'],
 ['James Madison']]
```

If you want to sort for shortest to longest, of course, you can just remove the `reverse=True`

Answer (score 1):

```
List = [['George Washington'],
 ['John Adams'],
 ['Thomas Jefferson'],
 ['James Madison'],
 ['James Monroe'],
 ['John Quincy Adams'],
 ['Andrew Jackson'],
 ['Martin Van Buren'],
 ['William Henry Harrison'],
 ['John TyIer']]

def func(name):
    fname = name[0].split()[0]
    return  len(fname)

print(sorted(List,key=func)[:6])
```